# How to reference a codeigniter function name as callback from native php function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm sure this must have been asked before somewhere, but I can't find the answer:

How do you reference the name of a Codeigniter function from the callback parameter of a native php function such as `array_map()`?

As a simple example, I have this code inside my `CI_Controller`:

```
function test(){
    $row = array('foo', 'bar');
    $new_row = array_map('do_the_mapping', $row);
    echo $new_row[0];
}

function do_the_mapping($row){
    return($row . $row);
}
```

`do_the_mapping()` is not finding the second function. So how do I reference it correctly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `do_the_mapping` is a method of an object, and not a global function (which is what you were implying by using `array_map('do_the_mapping'...`, you have to pass an array to the `array_map` function in the first parameter.

This array must consist of two items, the first (index 0) being a reference to your object's instance and the second (index 1) being the string representation of the method's name.

For example, if your controller resembles the following:

```
class Some_page extends CI_Controller {

    public function test()
    {
        $row = array('foo', 'bar');
        $new_row = array_map('do_the_mapping', $row);
        echo $new_row[0];
    }

    public function do_the_mapping($row)
    {
        return($row . $row);
    }

}
```

You would have to change this:

```
array_map('do_the_mapping', $row)
```

To this:

```
array_map(array($this, 'do_the_mapping'), $row);
```

If you wanted to call a method of another object, simple change `$this` to a reference to that object's instance.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you can provide the callback like this, because `do_the_mapping` is a function of the controller object. You would have to change the function to be static according to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

```
<?php
class Foo extends CI_Controller {

    public static function do_the_mapping($row) {
        return ($row . $row);
    }
}
```

and call it like `array_map("Foo::do_the_mapping", $row);`.

[edit] Reading the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) more thoroughly you don't need a static function but can provide the object to the callback: `array_map(array($this, "do_the_mapping"), $row);`.